# Solidworks, Pattern on a cicular surface

Tags: solidworks

I got an assignment and I have a difficult time making a pattern on a circular surface. I have no idea what I should google or do to obtain the same figure as below:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making the cylindrical handle, do a cut-revolve for the groove then array it using a circular pattern.  Adding an axis to the body of the handle will give you something to revolve the pattern around.